# Unlocking capability of a locked Samsung Galaxy J3 Emerge phone only for medical purpose

Tags: applications, google-play-store, browser, samsung-galaxy-j3

I have just been given a very special type of a phone and I want to know what I can do with it. Let me explain my situation:

I just got a Medtronic pain pump installed via surgery and after I was given a Samsung Galaxy J3 Emerge phone to control it. When they gave it to me, they just said it is to control the pump and nothing else could be done with it. Yeah I do not believe that.

I researched the phone and found that it is a Samsung Galaxy J3 Emerge that runs Android 7.0. The phone looks like it is capable of everything a normal phone can do so I ordered it a case.

Medtronic has basically taken all the apps off the phone like internet browsing, Google Play Store, app to make phone calls, and a texting app. They then installed all of their apps like one to control the pain pump, a web browser the doctor can use in his office, and a user manual for the pump.

I connected it to my Wi-Fi already. What I want to know is, how do I put a web browser, the Google Play Store, and all the regular apps back on it?

I do not want to delete or mess up the pain pump controls but I want to try to use this phone like a regular phone and unlock its full potential.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Sorry but we don't know how Medtronic locked this device. Furthermore most unlocking methods involves factory reset. Kindly understand we won't help without more information.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT USE THE DEVICE FOR ANYTHING BUT WHAT MEDTRONIC SET IT UP FOR as ANY or all additional software (apps) often co-use code and you May open the MEDTRONIC Controller up to a plethora of vulnerabilities thus causing pain pump management System (galaxy phone) to received improper direction which may lead to over or under medicating.